# Ngb Carousel has a strange behaviour

Tags: html, css, web, carousel, ng-bootstrap

I'm developing a website and i'm trying to add a carousel from Ngb.

I followed the tutorial to add it but it is not working: my three images are placed one after the other and the text is superimposed at the bottom of the third page.

I check my package.json and the line `"@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^2.2.0"` is present. I also `add import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap'` and `NgbModule.forRoot()` in my app.modules.ts and copied pasted the example from the Ngb bootstrap website but the problem is present.

For information, my IDE (WebStorm) is telling me that the `ngb-carousel` tag is unknown and that the attribute `ngbSlide` is not allowed but i have no error during the compilation.

I hope you're gonna be able to help me and i'm ready to add some come here if you need.

Thanks !

Comment: Not enough info here to be sure but if I would have to guess I would assume that you didn't include Bootstrap CSS.

Comment: hi,
thanks for your answer
i used another carousel (ngx one) because i had too much problems with the ngb carousel
it works well even if there is no transition

thanks again